What concerns should I have when using server-side sockets?
My question is quite simple. I'm developing a chat server that communicates after generating a ticket, but I only do the basics: open the connection, listen to events, and that's it. Should I worry about any performance issues that online articles don't explain? I really want to avoid creating a bottleneck and I need to be aware of concerns a large application using sockets might have.
For context: The backend is being developed in NestJS.
I only do the basics: open the connection, listen to events, and that's it.


Scalability: what is the max number of open sockets you can have
Concurrency: what happens if some actions are conflicting, how do you resolve that: ex 1 user edits a message which is deleted by another
Resource Management: Mind the content you are sending in chat, try to limit it
Error Handling: situations like reloading the app, loosing connection (mostly mobile) any other runtime errors could lead to loosing the websocket connection, think how to prevent and restore communication in this cases
Security: Ensure that your server is secure against common security threats, such as denial-of-service (DoS) attacks, buffer overflows, and injection attacks. Use secure protocols like TLS/SSL for encrypting communication and implement proper authentication and authorization mechanisms to control access to resources.

Other things to take into account:

monitoring and logging
load balancing
caching
costs

